# how to distribute clients with due amounts over agents based on amounts on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, analysis

i'm not sure how to put it right but bear with me.
let's say i own a company and i have like 5 clients who owe me money.
so, i hired 3 agent to try retrieve the money for me for a commission of 20% of the retrieved money.
i want to distribute these clients over the 5 agents evenly or semi-evenly based on the amount of money owed.

Client 1 owes me 1000

Client 2 owes me 2000

Client 3 owes me 3000

Client 4 owes me 2000

Client 5 owes me 4000

---

Agent 1 will take Client 1, 3 (Total amount of money is 4k)

Agent 2 will take Client 2, 4 (Total amount of money is 4k)

Agent 3 will take Client 5 (Total amount of money is 4k)

but let's say i have like 20k clients with due amounts of whole and rational amounts,
i know there's no way to distribute it evenly over agents but we can set a limit for the money given to each agent.
like if the total amount of money is 353,464.42 each agent should take around 117,821,47 give or take.

how to come up with a formula to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your question is perhaps more mathematical than excel related. Perhaps think of a way you state the question which is a bit more generic, something like "how to sort numbers evenly in multiple buckets". Keep in mind superuser is meant to help more than just one person with an single problem but rather help several people with a similar and searchable question. None the less, I'll take a crack at it.

Comment: “how to come up with a formula to do this?” This is the core problem with this question: This is not a coding or scripting service. This site helps people who help themselves and without showing any of your code or formula efforts, you are effectively asking the community to do work for you. Please add whatever  code or formula you might have and this community can help you. As it stands this question should be closed due to the issues outlined at the beginning of my comment.

Comment: Can you provide sample tables about the problem and result you need?

Comment: You need to determine what your "even distribution" criterion actually amounts to. If the data do not allow the allocation problem to be performed in a way that allocates the same amount to each agent then what are you going to use as a criterion to judge whether one allocation is better than another. There are several statistically inspired measures that are obvious candidates. Once you have such a criterion in mind it is possible that the Solver add-in might be useful in performing the necessary optimisation against it.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine you are trying to share a Flake chocolate evenly between say 3 kids. You brake the flake into random pieces. You'd start by handing out the biggest pieces first and balance them out as you go along.

I'd try and do the same in Excel. Sort the number large to small. Then add a column "assign to" and add the formula to row 2 (assuming a header row)

```
=MOD(ROW()-2,n)+1
```

Where n is the number of buckets or agents. This would create a repeating pattern 1..n 1..n 1..n (e.g. 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3), effectively assigning each row to a bucket or agent number.

* If the number of rows (20000?) are a lot larger than n (3?), and there are few outliers (no single big numbers), this should be sufficient in balancing the numbers.

You can use SUMIF to sum the totals per bucket or agent number and check if they are balanced enough.

If those assumptions* aren't valid, you might need to take a more literal flake sharing approach and assign numbers based on the current lowest running total. In the sorted list assign 1..n for the first n data rows. Then in column B row n+2 (assuming A1 is "values" and B1 is "assign to")

```
=LET(runtot, SUMIF($B$2:Bm, {1, 2, ... n}, $A$2:Am), MATCH(MIN(runtot), runtot, 0))
```

Where m is replaced with the value of n+1, and the static array is actually written out from 1 to n. If you don't have Excel 365 and the LET function, just use the final MATCH equation and replace runtot with the SUMIF formula twice. If you are in any case going to have extra columns for the individual bucket running totals, you might as well use those instead of calculating it once more in a single formula.